# How to get the key of created with db.run_in_transaction record?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I tried to create the record in the datastore with my own key:

```py
class Counter(db.Model):
    counter = db.IntegerProperty()

def increase_counter(key):
    obj = db.get(key)
    if obj is None:
        obj = Counter(key_name=key, counter=1)
    else:
        obj.counter += 1
    obj.put()

db.run_in_transaction(increase_counter, "z"+intValue1+"_"+intValue2+"_"+intValue3)
```

It returns

> BadKeyError: Invalid string key z523068_139840081_879156.

Since it doesn't work, how can I know which key is created for my record? Can `db.Key()` can be used with `db.run_in_transaction`? How should I create counter first time and then increase the value with automatically generated key?

**Upd.** I've also tried the following:

```py
def increase_counter(key):
    if key is None:
        obj = Counter(counter=1)
    else: 
        obj = db.get(key)
        obj.counter += 1
    obj.put()
    return obj.key()

db_counter_key = None # initially we don't have key value
for argument in files_arguments:
    db_counter_key = db.run_in_transaction(increase_counter, db_counter_key)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a key_name, so you should use `get_by_key_name` instead of `db.get`:

```
class Counter(db.Model):
    counter = db.IntegerProperty()

def increase_counter(key_name):
    obj = Counter.get_by_key_name(key_name)
    if obj is None:
        obj = Counter(key_name=key_name, counter=1)
    else:
        obj.counter += 1
    return obj.put()

db.run_in_transaction(increase_counter, "z"+intValue1+"_"+intValue2+"_"+intValue3)
```

Edit. If you really need to pass a key, you can use this:

```
def increase_counter(key, amount=1):
    obj = db.get(key) if key else None
    if obj:
        obj.counter += amount
    else:
        obj = Counter(counter=amount)

    return obj.put()

db_counter_key = None # initially we don't have key value
db_counter_key = db.run_in_transaction(increase_counter, db_counter_key, 
                                       amount=len(files_arguments))
```

(following your example, you don't need to run multiple transactions and can instead pass an `amount` argument as the increment value)

Notice that you can return `obj.put()`, because `put()` returns the entity key.